# int[] does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, console-application

I am trying to pass an int[] into the method, concatenate it with another array and return it to main to print in the console. 
Here is the code:

```
//where preTemp is another array derived in previous method
public static int[] sesLayer(int[] preTemp)
{
    //set two arrays for rtr and r1r0
    int[] r1r0 = new int[2] { 0, 0 };
    int[] RTR = new int[1] { 0 };

    //add r1r0 to the preTemp int array
    //set length of the new array to accomodate temp + r1r0
    var length = new int[preTemp.Length + r1r0.Length];
    r1r0.CopyTo(length, 0);
    preTemp.CopyTo(length, length.Length);

    //add RTR to the packet

    return preTemp;
}
public static int[] preLayer(int tempData)
{
            string binaryTemp = Convert.ToString(tempData, 2);
            int DLC = binaryTemp.Length;
            binaryTemp = binaryTemp.PadLeft(64, '0');

            string binaryDLC = Convert.ToString(DLC, 2);
            binaryDLC = binaryDLC.PadLeft(4, '0');

            string prePacket = binaryDLC + binaryTemp;

            //convert string to int[]
            int[] preTemp = prePacket.Select(c =>      int.Parse(c.ToString())).ToArray();
            return preTemp;
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] sesTemp = sesLayer(preTemp);    //**error crops up here**
    Console.Write(sesTemp);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

and the int tempData  = 58;
Any help appreciated.

Comment: where do you declare and initialize `preTemp`?

Comment: That's the problem, the OP isn't.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: In your Main() method, preTemp is initialized nowhere. Isn't that your problem?

Comment: sorry, changed it now.

Comment: it is initialized.

Comment: Add code that can be run and that actually displays the issue you're seeing. Make sure it's an exact copy - an error like this can easily be caused by a misplaced `;` or something similar. Do the same with the error message - I assume it's something more like "The name 'preTemp' doesn't exist in the current context." :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is pretty clear. You're calling a variable that doesn't exist.

```
int[] sesTemp = sesLayer(preTemp);
```

You have no variable named `preTemp` within the scope of your `Main()` method. You're only using it as arguments for your methods. You'll have to create a new variable.

```
int[] preTemp = new int[] { /* your values */ };
int[] sesTemp = sesLayer(preTemp);
```

Comment: As far as I am concerned the `preLayer` returns an int [] array which is 64 in length.
Hence the variable does exist in my opinion.

Comment: Any variables you initialize in a method are contained within that method. Create one in the `Main()` method and try to use it in `preLayer`. That's another way you can reproduce your error.

Comment: Got it! Thank you Drew :)

Comment: Glad to have helped. :)